# jquery contenteditable issue

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

i'm somewhat new to html5 and i'm trying to implement its contenteditable attribute through jquery and i have this

```
    var note = document.forms["form"]["add"].value;
    $("body").append("<div class=\"post_it\"><div class=\"flag\"></div><span class=\"note\" contenteditable=\"true\">" + note + "</span></div>");
```

now everything works except for the contenteditable feature? the div is appended and whatnot but i still can't edit it and i'm not quite sure why

Comment: oh that's really strange... it's probably something else in my code that does it? is there any way i can get the contenteditable effect with jquery instead of html5 i might want to try that out

Answer (score 0):

Here's the support for content editable across browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable